# Local Human task service jBPM

Tags: java, workflow, jbpm

I am using jBPM 5.3.0, but i have a problem when i try to implement LocalTaskService for Human Task.

I try this code:

```
            org.jbpm.task.service.TaskService taskService = new org.jbpm.task.service.TaskService(getEntityManagerFactory(), SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener());
        SyncWSHumanTaskHandler syncWSHumanTaskHandler = new SyncWSHumanTaskHandler();
        syncWSHumanTaskHandler.setLocal(true);
        TaskService localTaskService = new LocalTaskService(taskService);
        syncWSHumanTaskHandler.setClient(localTaskService);
        getKnowledgeSession().getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", syncWSHumanTaskHandler);
```

But it seems that the SyncWSHumanTaskHandler is deprecated.

So i would like to know if someone implement it in the last release of jBPM and have some samples.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find unit tests that shows the functionality:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/test/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/wsht/local/sync/WSHumanTaskHandlerLocalSyncTest.java
That test shows how to use the new classes. As I've already answered here:
https://community.jboss.org/message/738956

We are trying to keep all the implementation aligned with the same names for all the transports and for the async and sync implementations. The new Human Task WorkItemHandlers are called:
AbstractHTWorkItemHandler -> GenericHTWorkItemHandler & AsyncGenericHTWorkItemHandler -> Then the concrete implementation for the different transports: LocalHTWorkItemHandler, HornetQHTWorkItemHandler and Mina...

Using LocalTaskService is ok.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the double post. But There is a problem, The LocalHTWorkItemHandler doesn't exist in the 5.3.0 version of jBPM. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The LocalHTWorkItemHandler is a simple extension of the GenericHTWorkItemHandler, take a look in github master you will see that simple class that you can copy in your project if you need it.
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/wsht/LocalHTWorkItemHandler.java

Comment: yes i see this but i need the GenericHTWorkItemHandler class too because the registerTaskEvents() method is private and not protected in the 5.3.0 final version.

Comment: The github link above is broken

Comment: What is the jBPM 6.3 version of the AbstractHTWorkItemHandler?

Comment: Same class just under a different package: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.3.x/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/services/task/wih/AbstractHTWorkItemHandler.java